# Text overlapping in tabularx

Tags: tabularx, text

I have a tabularx table, and it's an overlapping of the text there. How to fix that?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[russian]{babel} 
\usepackage{multirow,tabularx}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=1in,landscape]{geometry}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|X|X|X|X|X|X|c|c|}
\hline
\multirow{2}*{N} & \multirow{2}*{Название, марка, модель обуродования} & \multirow{2}*{Количество} & \multirow{2}*{Серийный номер} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Технические харектеристики} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Поверка} \\   \cline{5-8}
   &  & &       & Н & Д & последняя   & следующая   \\ \hline
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main point is to replace the `*` argument to `\multirow`, which means ‘use the  natural width of the contents’  with `\linewidth`, i.e. the width of an `X` column. I added some improvements to your code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[russian]{babel}
\usepackage{multirow,tabularx}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=1in,landscape, showframe]{geometry}

\begin{document}

\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.5}
\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|X|X|X|X|X|X|c|c|}
  \hline
  \multirow{2}{\linewidth}{N} & \multirow{2}{\linewidth}{Название, марка, модель обуродования} & \multirow{2}{\linewidth}{Количество} & \multirow{2}{\linewidth}{Серийный номер} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Технические харектеристики} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Поверка} \\ \cline{5-8}
    & & & & Н & Д & последняя & следующая \\ \hline
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

[image]